# Send an Id of a database between 2 pages in php

Tags: php, database

I want to send a "ID" who is it in my data base between 2 php pages. Basically in "showDocuments", I show a list of documents and in "ShowFiche" I want to show especially the documents but now in my code, i show a document with no variable.
here you have my date base: Table document with ID, NOM, AUTEUR
thx all for yours answers and sorry for my english, i m french !

Page 1 :

```
  public function ShowDocuments ($_value)
  {
    $_POST['ID'] = 1;
    echo 'Liste des documents';
    $nb = count ($_value['data']['NOM']);
    for ($i = 0, $tr = ''; $i < $nb; ++$i)
    {
      $mod = $i%2;
      $param = 'EX=form&ID='.$_value['data']['ID'][$i];

      $tr .= <<<HERE
<tr class="ligne$mod">
 <td><a href="../Php/appli.php?EX=fiche"> {$_value['data']['NOM'][$i]}....................</a></td>
<td>{$_value['data']['AUTEUR'][$i]}....................</td>
</tr>

HERE;

    }
```

Page 2 :

```
public function ShowFiche()
  {
   $Id_Var = $_GET['ID'];
  $db = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', 'root'); 

      // on sélectionne la base 
      mysql_select_db('BaseTp',$db); 

      $sql = 'SELECT NOM, AUTEUR FROM DOCUMENTS WHERE ID = 0'; 

      // on envoie la requête 
      $req = mysql_query($sql) or die('Erreur SQL !<br>'.$sql.'<br>'.mysql_error()); 

      // on fait une boucle qui va faire un tour pour chaque enregistrement 



      while($data = mysql_fetch_assoc($req)) 
      { 
          echo 'Titre : ' . $data['NOM'] .'<br><br>' . 'Auteur : ' . $data['AUTEUR']; 
      } 


      mysql_close(); 

    echo $_value['ID'][$i];

HERE;

  }
```

Comment: have you tried session variables?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [setcookie()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php) function to store a cookie and use it whenever needed

**Example Code**

```
//Check if cookie exists
if (isset($_COOKIE['uid'])) {
    //Get UID from cookie
    $uid = $_COOKIE['uid'];
} else {
    //Generate UID
    $uid = uniqid();
    //Store in cookie
    setcookie('uid',$uid);
}
```

Comment: Rely on cookie for id is not a good idea, use session instead.

Comment: Sorry but my project rules doestn't want i use cookies :)

Comment: it is there in my answer... Click on `setcookie()` you will get new page... check there

Answer (score 0):

How do you expect the magic to happen? You need to explicitly call `showFiche` from page2.
Moreover, you don't `return` your line from `ShowDocuments` so no output should be expected. And last but not least, your request is not parametrized by the ID you're grabbing…

```
// page1.php

function showDocuments() {
   $str = '';
   $str .= 'mystuff from database, including links to page2.php?id=…';
   return $str;
}

echo showDocuments();

// page2.php
if (isset($_GET['id'])) {
  $id = int($_GET['id']);
  showFiche ($id);
} else { echo "no id given!"; }
```

But keep in mind that your code is a mess:

- Database related parameters should be in a config file
- Database access should be abstracted using builtin [php PDO module](http://php.net/pdo)
- A function is supposed to make some operations, and computations, and return a set of results (with array for instance). All the makeup should be done outside. Same for error handling.

Hope this helps :)